# Write n first elements from bst

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I want to print only n first elements from bst tree so i added global variable  counter

```
int a = 0;
void print (wezel **korzen,int x)
{
    if((*korzen) != NULL && (a < x))
    {
        print( &((*korzen)->lewe),x );
        a++;
        printf("%s %d\n", (*korzen)->wartosc, (*korzen)->ile);
        print( &((*korzen)->prawe),x );
    }
}
```

but this condition in if does not work ? where i made mistake ?

Comment: Where is `a` defined/initialised?

Comment: What is `a`? The code doesn't include a declaration of that variable, so it's hard to tell. Also, you should skip the global and instead have a "current depth" argument (use a dedicated iteration function to keep the external API).

Comment: You increment a after you call print on lewe. You need to check a's value after that print call.

Comment: is `a` you global variable? you need to set it `0` before call of your BST's`print()`

Comment: its set to 0 :) it just not stop ever

Comment: @whd you might want to read http://sscce.org/ for future reference

Comment: How do you define `n first elements`? clearly not root down, Looks like you're going all the way left, then printing, then going right and trying to go left again if possible... so you want "first n" left most elements? Which elements in a BST are "first" in your mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you don't check a after the first print:

```
int a = 0;
void print (wezel **korzen,int x)
{
    if((*korzen) != NULL && (a < x))
    {
        print( &((*korzen)->lewe),x );
        // A has incremented since last check
        if (a < x) {
            printf("%s %d\n", (*korzen)->wartosc, (*korzen)->ile);
            a++;
            print( &((*korzen)->prawe),x );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mention `a` should be set to `0` before call of print. other condition may fail in 2 consecutive runs